# Reopen votes review queue asks "Nominate for reopening?" when one clicks "Leave Closed"

Tags: bug, user-interface, review, re-open

With the recent redesign of the whole close system, there seems to have been an inadvertent corollary.

Namely, in the "Reopen Votes" review queue, when one clicks "Leave Closed", there is a popup saying "Nominate this question for **reopening**?"

Screenshot:

[image: Bug screenshot]

Clicking Cancel records a "Leave Closed" review (thanks Asaf for digging that up). I haven't tried what OK does.

As the observant have undoubtedly inferred, I use Chrome (latest) and Windows (7).

Comment: "Lord_Farin reviewed this 1 hour ago: Leave Closed"

Comment: Thanks; edited (also to clear up the ambiguous "it"). (NB. I actually went to the question afterwards, to vote to reopen. This particular question was only used to obtain the screenshot.)

Comment: Cf. [MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184603/222340).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The devs have solved it. Emmett wrote ([Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186188/222340)):

> Oops, this was caused by a javascript copy-paste gone awry. It's fixed now – sorry about that.